# How to provide public read access to a all files in folder by s3fs in node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-rename, file-access

How to provide public read access to a all files in folder by s3fs in node.js?

I am trying to rename the folder name by using following code:

```
  fsImpl.mkdirp(main_folder_path).then(function () {
                        fsImpl.copyDir(copy_folder_path+'/', main_folder_path+'/').then(function () {
                                console.log("copy directory")
                            }, function (reason) {
                                res.json('error');
                            });
                        });
```

Successfully all files are get copying to new folder,But the copies files don't have public access..I have searched some sources and finally i get following answer

```
fsImpl.writeFile(fileName, stream,{ACL: 'public-read'}).then(function (err,data) {  
     // code
 })
```

But I need to give access to the folder . How do i do that??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did your S3 bucket have public read access?? if not go to your S3 account and there you find Permissions Tab after click on that you will have three new Tabs. from those tabs Click on Bucket Policy. and Add the following JSON code there.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket name/*"
    }
]}
```

It will resolve your problem.

Comment: I am giving public access only when i am uploading the file..but while copying from one folder to another using s3fs npm there is no public access

Comment: might be this link helps you. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon

Comment: @Priyanklohan note that s3fs-fuse is not the same thing as [s3fs for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs).  Only the name is the same.